# How can I get a property name for a type without the need to instantiate an object of that type?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, types, properties

I have a requirement where I need to have a "type safe" way of accessing property names, without actually instantiating an object to get to the property.  To give an example, consider a method that takes as arguments a list of IMyObject and a string that represents a property name (a property that exists in IMyObject).

The methods implementation will take the list and access all the objects in the list using the property name passed... for some reason or another, we won't dwell on that!!

Now, I know that you can do this using an instantiated object, something like ...

```
Dim x as MyObject = nothing
Dim prop As PropertyInfo = PropHelper.GetProperty(Of MyObject)(Function() x.MyProperty)
```

Where my helper method uses reflection to get the name of the property as a string - there are numerous examples of this flying around on the web!

But I don't want to have to create this pointless object, I just want to do something like MyObject.MyProperty!  Reflection allows you to iterate through a types properties and methods without declaring an object of that type... but I want to access a specific property and retrieve the string version of its name without iteration and without declaring an object of that type!

The main point here is that although I am trying to get the property name as a string... this is done at run time... at compile time, I want this to be type safe so if someone changes the property name, the compilation will break.

Can anyone help in this quest!?!

Comment: How would it get a compile error if it is just using a string variable to store a property name?  The only way to accomplish that is to automate some code generation and then compile the generated code.  Then that compile will fail.  But if you're using reflection at runtime, there's no way to make that fail with a compile error.

Comment: Just want to make the code type-safe.  So I want to avoid a call like: CallMethod(_myList, "MyProperty") .... and make a call something like: Callmethod(_myList, MyObject.MyProperty) .... thus the former will compile even when another developer changes the actual property name... whereas the latter will throw a compile time error.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That makes more sense now.  This reminds me.  Some of the unit testing frameworks like NUnit and Moq do this kind of thing with lambda expressions.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to pass the property in as a simple lamdba expression, and take it in the method as an expression tree.  You should be able to analyze the expression tree to get the string name of the property, but it the lambda expression will fail to compile if the property name changes.  Check out this page for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: Yep, found a solution based on expressions.  I will post it up next time I am at my pc!  Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 5):

So here is a quick code-listing to demonstrate the answer that I was looking for:

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

Public Class A
    Public Prop1 As String
    Public Prop2 As Integer
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Public Function GetPropertyNameB(Of TModel, TProperty)(ByVal [property] As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TProperty))) As String
        Dim memberExpression As MemberExpression = DirectCast([property].Body, MemberExpression)
        Return memberExpression.Member.Name
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim propertyName As String = GetPropertyNameB(Function(myObj As A) myObj.Prop1)
        Dim propertyName2 As String = GetPropertyNameB(Function(myObj As A) myObj.Prop2)
        MsgBox(propertyName & " | " & propertyName2)
        End
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the NameOf function:

```
Dim fieldName = nameOf(MyClass.MyField)
```